# Concatenate multiple files from different directories

Tags: wildcards

I want to concatenate multiple files from different directories.

Directory 1: `Chr1` containing (in this example) four files:

```
ABC.1 
DEF.1
GHI.1 
JKL.1
```

Directory 2: `Chr2`

```
ABC.2  
DEF.2 
GHI.2
JKL.2
```

There are 22 directories.
Each file has 20 columns with a header. The headers are the same for all files.

I want to concatenate all into one file (one global output file for the concatenation of all files from all directories).

I tried this but this does not work.

```
cat */Chr{1..22}/*.{1..22} > */final_file
```

It said that "No such file or directory", as there are no files, for example, for *.1~21 for the files in the directory of chr22.

Do you have any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: So basically the suffix of the filenames in each directory is the same as the trailing number of the directory name? Also, please edit your post to include specifically in what way your command didn't work.

Comment: yes, for the directory of chr 1, all files are *.1. For the directory of chr22, all files are *.22.

Comment: One global output file for the concatenation of all files from all directories.

Comment: Is the ordering of the files relevant?

Comment: No it does not matter.

Comment: Each directory has 48 files. I just showed only 4 files as an example. Each file has more than 200 lines.

Comment: There are other txt files in the directories besides the ones oyu want to concatenate?

Comment: And are the directories in the same path, with no other directories?

Comment: Is the header to appear only once in the resulting output file, or is it ok if it gets copied along with every new file appended to the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that repeated wildcard characters are not interpreted (="expanded") in a "synchronized" way, but anew and independently for every occurence on a command-line. Hence, you will need to operate with nested shell loops.

You could try the following shell script. Notice that it uses `bash` features (your question didn't include what shell you are using)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

hdr=0   # initialize variable to keep track of whether the header is already printed

# loop over directories
for d in Chr*
do
    # extract trailing number from dir name by removing 'Chr' part (bash feature!)
    n="${d#Chr}"

    # loop over all files
    for f in "$d/"*".$n"
    do
       if (( hdr == 0 )) # if header wasn't printed yet, output entire file
       then
           cat "$f" > final_file
           hdr=1
       else              # otherwise, output file content starting with line 2
           tail -n +2 "$f" >> final_file
       fi
    done
done
```

You can name the script `concatenate.sh`, make it executable, and run it from the directory where all your `Chr{1..22}` subdirectories are located. The `final_file` will be created in that directory, too.

Notice I couldn't test it very far, but it shouldn't destroy anything ...

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `zsh` shell instead:

```
cat -- */Chr<1-22>/*.<1-22>(n) > final_file
```

In `zsh`, `<x-y>` is a glob operator that matches on ranges of decimal integer numbers, and the `n` glob qualifier toggles the `numericglobsort` option which causes glob expansions to be sorted numerically.

From within another shell, you can do:

```
zsh -c 'cat -- */Chr<1-22>/*.<1-22>(n) > final_file'
```

To skip the header on all but the first file, and assuming the GNU or busybox implementation of `tail` (the most common on systems using Linux as their kernel), you can do:

```
(){
  cat < $1; shift; (($#)) && tail -qn +2 -- "$@"
} */Chr<1-22>/*.<1-22>(n) > final_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture all the files in all your subdirectories `Chr.*` you could use this

```
cat Chr*/* >final_file
```

If you need to restrict the set of files in each subdirectory to match the suffix of that directory's name (so in `Chr1` we only consider files matching `*.1`) you will need a loop

```
shopt nullglob    # This is bash-specific
for i in {1..22}
do
    cat Chr$i/*.$i
done >final_file
```

The optional `shopt nullglob` tells the shell that if a wildcard cannot match it's to be removed rather than being left as a literal asterisk.

As an alternative, since there seems to be some feeling that you want all but the first header line omitted from your concatenated files, this expanded loop can handle it

```
first=yes
for i in {1..22}
do
    for f in Chr$i/*.$i
    do
        [[ -n "$first" ]] && head -n1 "$f" && first=
        cat "$f"
    done
done >final_file
```

Or if your header line exists as the first line of the first file, and can thereafter be removed whereever it's encountered, you can strip it using a construct like this

```
for i in {1..22}
do
    cat Chr$i/*.$i
done |
    awk '$0 != header { print } header == "" { header = $0 }' >final_file
```

Comment: The problem is that the first line of _every_ file contains a header that is to appear only once in the overall result file, so you will need to include some test on that ...

Comment: It doesn't say that anywhere in the question. The OP's example doesn't attempt to handle that either

Comment: Well, I don't see any other reason why the OP should mention the (globally identical) header in the first place if it isn't to be treated specially ...

Comment: I've seen a lot of questions where information is supplied simply because the asker doesn't know if it's relevant or not.